# Why I obtain this error message when I try to compile cgminer? autoreconf error

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, make, autoconf

I am trying to install **Cgminer** on my RaspBerry (it use RaspBian that is a Debian minimalistic version) as explained here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494625.0

In particular the installation steps are these:

```
git clone https://github.com/gridseed/usb-miner/
cd usb-miner/software/cgminer
autoreconf -i
./configure --enable-gridseed
make
```

I have some problem when I try to execute the third step infact when I try to execute the **autoreconf** command I obtain the following error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/download/usb-miner/software/cgminer $ autoreconf -i
autom4te: cannot create autom4te.cache: No such file or directory
aclocal: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Why? What can I do to solve this issue?

What exactly do the autoreconf command? and what is the **autom4te.cache**?

Tnx

Comment: Its a cache file.  Its attempting to generate the file in that folder on your system, and either at folder does not exist or the permissions are wrong.

Comment: mmm and what can I try to do to solve this issue?

Comment: create the folder with the correct permissions

Comment: mmm but what folder? and where?

Comment: rhe folder is: "/download/usb-miner/software/cgminer" or "/usr/bin/autom4te" or what else?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is the build script was unable to create a file called `autom4te.cache` in the folder `/usr/bin/autom4te `

Comment: I got exactly the same error message, albeit from a completely different repo. In my case `/usr/bin/autom4te` already existed. But then the command succeeded when I ran it as root.

Comment: I solved it,try this:
`sudo ./autogen.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo was created/cloned by a different user than the one doing the compile. So the user doing the compile does not have write permission in the folders where compilation wants to write `autom4te.cache`

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/download/usb-miner/software/cgminer
```

Will fix the problem - by user `pi` taking ownership of the repo directory, thus allowing compilation by user `pi` to write in those folders.